# HTML5 <audio> textTrack.kind=subtitles cueChange event not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

### UPDATE:

This issue no longer existing FireFox, cuechange now works.  Embedded base64 images also render.

The original code is a simple implementation of am MP3 player with captioning using HTML5 `<AUDIO>` and a few lines of JavaScript.

The example Audio Player HTML has a .VTT subtitle file with embedded images using Base64.

### ORIGINAL POST BEGINS HERE

I am using the HTML5 `<audio>` Player 
with a VTT subtitle `<track>`

**The Player and lyrics VTT subtitles (with images)  work fine with Google Chrome Version 35.**

[Click Here for: Link to the html page that works in 
Google Chrome but not FireFox](http://islmpeg.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/SeasonsInTheSun.html)
**Now the above link works in Firefox with workaround below.**

**FireFox Version 35 can play the mp3, but the VTT subtitles do not work properly.**

The onCueChange and cueChange events both work in Chrome
Neither onCueChange nor cueChange events work in FireFox

### New Update Added Below With Simple Workaround (1/26/16)

**OnCueChange embedded in HTML**

```
<track id="trk" kind="subtitles"  onCueChange="cueChange()" srclang="en" src="SeasonsInTheSun.vtt" default />
```

**cueChange Event Listener**

```
track.addEventListener("cuechange", cueChange, false);
```

How it works
When the VTT time changes the audio.track generates a cueChange Event.
In the below VTT cues (2 of 25) the cueChange Event should fire at `00:00:00.001` and `00:00:04.200`
When the event fires, the script then reads the `activeCues[0].text`
The `activeCues.text` is displayed in the  `<div id="lyrics> innerHTML`

**WEBVTT**

```
00:00:00.001 --> 00:00:04.000
Seasons in the Sun
Terry Jacks
00:00:04.200 --> 00:00:20.000
Goodbye to you, my trusted friend
We've known each other since we were nine or ten
Together we climbed hills and trees
```

[Click Here for Link to full .vtt](http://islmpeg.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/SeasonsInTheSun.vtt)

This .vtt in addition to the lyrics has embedded base64 images

NOTE: VTT must be served with an HTTP header MIME Type of `Content-Type:text/vtt`

**I have confirmed via Firebug the Following:**

- The VTT file loads with out Error.
- The acvtiveCues has correct length and text.
- The 25 cues from the VTT file are loaded and correct
- The textTrack mode is "showing"

**Full HTML with JavaScript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Seasons in the Sun</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,body{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;background-color:#000;color:#f0f;}
#lyrics{margin-left:3em;font: 700 2.3em arial,sans-serif;color:#0ff;text-align:center;}
</style></head><body>
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" controls>
<source src="http://islmpeg.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/TerryJacks-SeasonsInTheSun.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<track id="trk" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="http://islmpeg.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/SeasonsInTheSun.vtt" default  />
</audio>
<br/><div id="lyrics"></div><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var lyrics = document.getElementById('lyrics');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var track = document.getElementById('trk');
var textTrack = track.track;
track.addEventListener("cuechange", cueChange, false);

function init(){audio.volume = .3;audio.play();}
function cueChange(){
var cues = textTrack.activeCues;
if (cues.length > 0){
lyrics.innerHTML = cues[0].text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');}}
window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script></body></html>
```

### Update Work Around
Works in FireFox and Chrome

Still not working in FireFox 45 (Jan 26, 2016)
**UPDATE:  cueChange NOW WORKING IN FIREFOX**
**THIS FIX NO LONGER NEEDED FOR FIREFOX**

The text captions work in MS Edge, but does not render the Base64 Images**
**Code does not work in IE 11** 
 
I never tried to get it running in IE as I would never use a MS product unless absolutely necessary and this project is only for myself.  I may in the future work on IE or maybe someone else posted a solution for IE.
UPDATE: Not going to check if fit works with MS crap.

I added a JS Timer to call cueChange() every 500 milliseconds

```
var nIntervId=window.setInterval(function(){cueChange()},500);
```

I removed this which worked in Chrome:

```
track.addEventListener("cuechange", cueChange, false);
```

### New Updated Code (UPDATE: no longer needed)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Seasons In The Sun</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,body{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;background-color:#000;color:#f0f;}
#lyrics{margin-left:3em;font: 700 2.3em Arial,sans-serif;color:#0ff;text-align:center;}
#html5{display:none;}
</style></head><body><div><div id="html5"><h2>You Browser Does not support Audio Captions<br/>You will not see the lyrics.</h2></div>
<audio id="audio" preload="auto" controls>
<source src="http://islmpeg.s3.amazonaws.com/mp3/TerryJacks-SeasonsInTheSun.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<track id="trk" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="SeasonsInTheSun.vtt" default  />
</audio>
<br/><div id="lyrics"></div><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var lyrics = document.getElementById('lyrics');
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
var track = document.getElementById('trk');
var textTrack = track.track;
//track.addEventListener("cuechange", cueChange, false);   // oncuechange 
var nIntervId=window.setInterval(function(){cueChange()},500);

function init(){audio.volume = .3;audio.play();cueChange();}
function cueChange(){
  var cues = textTrack.activeCues;
  if (cues.length > 0){
    lyrics.innerHTML = cues[0].text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  }
}
window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script><img width="1" height="1" src="pix.php?p=sits" alt="."/></body></html>
```

Comment: this is a known bug in ff https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=629350

Comment: @RachelGallen  Thanks, I searched Bugzilla for audio and only found a bug for x86 OSX.  I would never have thought to search for WEBVTT.  There is very little documentation on the `<audio>`, almost all subtitle examples I could find use the `<video>`, which is much simpler because the captions div is built in.  The `<audio>` is very simple once you know how to do it.

Comment: you're welcome. Good to know there's nothing wrong with your code!!! :)

Comment: Did you happen to play the mp3 in Chrome.  It's kind of cool because I embedded jpeg images using base64 encoding.  It's a funny and sad production.

Comment: i did yes, its way cool and i really like that song !

Comment: Still not working in FF 40.0. :(

Comment: Still not working in FF 45.0 but posted simple workaround update today.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox still (!) doesn't support `oncuechange` (as of v38.0, May 2015).  However, you can usually use `video.ontimeupdate` to achieve almost exactly the same thing, e.g.:

```
var videoElement = $("video")[0];
var textTrack = videoElement.textTracks[0];
if (textTrack.oncuechange !== undefined) {
  $(textTrack).on("cuechange", function() { ... });
} else {
  // some browsers don't support track.oncuechange, so...
  $(videoElement).on("timeupdate", function() { ... });
}
```

Comment: Stil not implemented, nothing on the horizon :(  I'm throwing some money on bountysource for this bug next week.  https://www.bountysource.com/issues/28443545-implement-cuechange-event

Answer (score 0):

Still not fixed as of v39, August 2015. Here's the ugly workaround I've been putting together to check for changes to the activeCues list. It's working as a proof of concept, now I need to rewrite my code for browsers that do properly support onCueChange so the fallback happens properly.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var t = v.textTracks;
var la = [];
for(l = 0; l < t.length; l++){
    la[l] = '';
};

var onchangeTest =  (function isEventSupported(eventName) {
    var isSupported = ('oncuechange' in t[0]);
    if (isSupported) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
})();

v.ontimeupdate = function(){
    if(!onchangeTest){
        var activeCues ="";
        var delim ="";
        for(i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
            if(t[i].kind == 'captions' || t[i].kind == 'subtitles'){
                delim = "<br />";  
            } else {
                delim = "\n";
            };
            a = v[i].activeCues;
            if(a){
                var tt = '';
                for(ii = 0; ii < a.length; ii++){
                    tt += a[ii].text + delim;  
                    if(tt !== la[i]){
                        la[i] = tt;
                        console.log('tt: ' + tt + ' la[' + i + ']: ' + la[i]);
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Added new update to question with simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Patches have now been added to mozilla-inbound to get these firing for media elements (it now works for video).  I will now be fixing the audio side, which just doesn't fire because there's no subtitle window.

https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/rev/8935a32269a5
https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/rev/e1d06acdeb7b
https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/rev/9f4d815bb9af

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer from [avaunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005915/avaunt)! I think there is a typo in initial code. When I tested it both in FireFox and IE, it didn't work.

The line in question is

```
a = v[i].activeCues;
```

and it should read

```
a = t[i].activeCues;
```

since `activeCues` is a property of the `textTracks` object, not `video` object. After this change, it works!

I tried to make this post as a reply to his post, but system did not let me. So adding it as an answer.

Comment: It's a pain, not being able to comment about corrections. But, that restriction also helps suppress spam and garbage. Earn some rep to get past that! In the mean time, use Answers only for answers.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad I appreciate it. Just thought I bring in my contribution to save someone the hassle of figuring out why code isn't working.

Comment: You can make a suggested edit to the post, you know. (When that's approved, +2 rep!) In the summary, be clear about WHY the change is being made; reviewers often discard changes to code as vandalism.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12399047)

Comment: Thanks @Mosgad. I tried that too, to make a suggested edit to the post. But since my change was less than minimum required characters (I believe 6), it didn't let me save, regarding my edit as insignificant. Anyway guys, thanks for clarifying process (thanks @gonz), I guess I will wait to earn reps. Was just trying to help someone right away! All good :)

Comment: @Kevo Welcome to the site! I'm sure you'll get rep soon and be able to help others in the best way possible. See you around.